# asp.net ListView SelectedIndex event

Tags: c#, events, listview, webforms

I have a listview and I need to perform certain actions based on OnSelectedIndexChanged which is fine.

But now I am getting an error about OnSelectedIndexChanging which is undefined. I have no need for that one. 
The strange thing is that the other day it wasn't giving that error while today it does.
Do I need to define it even though I am not using it? I rather not since it does a refresh of the page if its just there with no code behind (meaning you have to press the Select link on the listview twice)

I am also getting " raised event ItemDeleting which wasn't handled." error when I click on the Delete link which I was not getting the other day.

What can cause the 2 issues above?

Comment: were you perhaps using DataSourceId, and now databinding manually?

Comment: Basically DataSourceID is intiallised as "" on the .aspx and then I manually bind it in the code, to a method which takes a parameter from listbox.SelectedValue. (you muat click the listbox first) hence its "" in the .aspx since you only have the value after you click the listbox.

Comment: Any idea how to do this right? I need to click twice on the Select link to select a row item in the listview due to the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind listview to datasource at codebehind , you have to write some code in SelectedIndexChanging event.

So the code will be :

```
    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ListView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
        //bind listview again here !
    }
```

```
    onselectedindexchanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
```

I Hope This will Solves your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you delete `OnSelectedIndexChanging` from `aspx.cs` page but you should not delete this event from your `.aspx` page.So its try to invoke and rage error.Same case for `ItemDeleting`.

Comment: If I do that I get: The OnSelectedIndexChanging event handler cannot be an empty string.

Comment: Go to property ->event and delete `OnSelectedIndexChanging` from there.

Comment: The problem is that if I remove that I get: The ListView 'lvUserLeaveHistory' raised event OnSelectedIndexChanging which wasn't handled. 
Hence having to put it in to make it work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was binding the data source manually and not at start up.
The errors above have dissappeared once I initilize the data source along with the listview at start up.